# Как ссылаться на другое поле в yaml файле?

Tags: html, yaml

У меня есть вот такой yaml:

```yaml
profileStats: &profileStats "Карма: <b>${carma}</b>.\nНаписано постов: <b>${posts}</b>.\nНаписано коментариев: <b>${comments}</b>."
viewProfile:
  summary: "Профиль пользователя <b>${username}</b>:\n*profileStats"
  noUserIdProvided: "Не указан идентификатор пользователя"
profile:
  summary: "Привет, <b>${username}</b>, твой профиль:\n*profileStats"
  resetBtn: "Сбросить аккаунт"
  changeDescriptionBtn: "Изменить описание"
  confirmReset: "Введите ваше имя пользователя для подтверждения. Это действие будет невозможно отменить!"
  resetSuccess: "Аккаунт успешно сброшен"
  resetError: "Неверное имя пользователя"
```

Как видно я попытался использовать ссылки, но это не работает. Как я могу еще ссылаться на profileStats из любого другого поля?

Comment: Никак. YAML так не умеет

Comment: @AlexeyTen спасибо